# How to get a detailed, Kubuntu-like GUI for changing regional/locale settings without installing all of KDE?

Tags: gui, locale

Kubuntu's GUI ([like here](http://www.kubuntu.org/docs/kquickguide/C/ch03s07.html#regional-country)), for locale settings is very detailed. Is there a way to get a similar, detailed GUI outside of Kubuntu without installing the entire KDE desktop environment?

I have here a system with Xubuntu. I'm only interested in whatever tool allows changing all those regional settings.

Comment: What do you mean "outside"? What are you using? You can install KDE on any distribution and you can also use the KDE tools from another desktop environment, though not all functions will be relevant. Please [edit] your question and tell us what you are actually running and what options you want to be able to set.

Comment: Added clarifications. Basically, I'm looking for <this> in sudo apt-get install <this>.

Comment: That "Country/Region & Language" panel is from the KDE systemsettings program. I don't _think_ you can run it as a separate program.